# Angular maxlength attribute is preventing input?

Tags: angular

The old ng-maxlength="5" used to trip the field error on but would continue to allow input by the user.  The maxlength="5" seems to be preventing input.  Is it angular doing this as I have the novalidate on my form?  Should it be prevented as I see examples of folks actually testing for errors.maxlength?

Here is my form snippet:

```
<form #myForm="ngForm"  novalidate>

  <h2>{{ hero.name | uppercase }} Details</h2>
  <div><span>id: </span>{{hero.id}}</div>

    <input #inputElement name="heroName" class="form-control"  [(ngModel)]="hero.name" required maxlength="5" #heroName="ngModel">

</form>
```

We would like behavior like ng-maxlength as we think it is clearer to the user.  That is, rather than preventing input, allow the user to keep typing but show the error.  Am I doing something wrong or do we need to create our own custom validation directive to replace maxlength?

Comment: You could consider custom directive that will call custom `Validator` to validate length of input field, check out [this blog](https://codeburst.io/angular-4-custom-validation-for-template-based-forms-b7dee9be48a6)

Answer (score 4):

The attribute you are using is the default [HTML `maxlength` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#Attributes), which prevents further input after the maximum number of characters is reached. If you want to allow further input and track it, you will need to use a custom validation directive, as you suggested.